# Win10 Device Manager Replaces Valid Driver with Broken One on Restart

Tags: windows, bluetooth, device-manager

I'm having an issue where, when I restart Windows 10, my installed Bluetooth adapter is replaced with one that doesn't work. I then have to go into Device Manager, delete the bad adapter driver, then use the "Scan for hardware changes" function to reinstall it. It works every time, but it is a pain in the neck.

I'm developing a Bluetooth Low Energy device interface for a client and it's frustrating when it doesn't work, only to find out that I forgot to cycle the driver after a restart. The invalid driver looks like a valid, working Bluetooth radio in the section of my code that looks for a BT adapter.

After restart:

[image]

After uninstalling the adapter driver and running "Scan for hardware changes"
[image]

Comment: I am guessing some options, I did NOT face such issue. Guess_1. If you find Realtek Bluetooth related app installed under Add/Remove programs, uninstall it and restart. Guess_2. Take backup of registry and then delete any entries relevant to Realtek Bluetooth. Guess_3. There may be some Realtek Bluetooth service, trial disabling it. In all cases restart :-) windows. Try it at your risk.

Answer (score 0):

Using ajaykumarbasuthkar's (above comment) suggestion, I went in to the device manager and deleted the Bluetooth driver. Then found the folder "C:\Program Files\Realtech\Bluetooth" and in that folder was a CMD script for erasing the driver from the disk. I ran that script and everything was gone. I then restarted windows and lo and behold, there was my Realtech Bluetooth with all the associated devices.